# $GLOBALS[] local instance or all instances of page?

Tags: php

It seems like globals defined in an instance of a page exists until the page is done rendering and then gets removed. I am a little concerned that it might carry over to another instance of the a page being opened on the server like static variables do (atleast in ASPX they do). Does defining variables in the $GLOBALS array only exist for that instance of the page? Its a simple question but I really appreciate any help!

Comment: It would take less writing than the question to test your self.

Comment: What difference does it make for you?

Comment: something about teaching men to fish, rather than giving them fish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the variables in php live until php finishes its processing.

So after the response is generated - all the variables, connections, etc are lost